# Spring animation in Recyclerview Items

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

Need to implement Spring animation in Recyclerview item when Swipe up is done to the item in the **Recyclerview**. I have tried the spring animation but somehow not able to achieve the animation. Any suggestion or any other library is appreciated.

I am sharing the design template. Only I need to do is when swipe up is done to the item the item will move up a bit with little elevation and come back to its initial position.

I have tried with this animation library provided by Google but not able to achieve this inside list items

[Spring animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/spring-animation)

[image: This animation I need to achieve]

Comment: see `ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDraw*()` methods - they are called when you swipe your item giving you a chance to update its position/elevation/alpha/whatever

Comment: I have tried that elevation but black shadows are coming. beneath when shadows are removed then the effect is not visible

Comment: I don't need the shadows as shown in the image

Comment: @pskink I have tried your ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDraw*() solution but the problem is that horizontal scroll is not working properly now

Comment: can you just suggest me how  this can be handled

Comment: actually, setOnTouchListener is added to the whole view. So when I am trying to scroll the list  then item is also touched so the scroll is not working properly

Comment: @pskink am I clear to you

Comment: plz guys can anybody help

Comment: why guys giving minus vote. Is that so easy guys?